# How to remove multiple rows from TreeView in GTK#

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, gtk#

Removing multiple rows from a TreeView in mono GTK# has tripped me up a little bit lately and the answer wasn't a quick google search away so I'm posting this question here. It has been extra problematic removing multiple rows when using sorting with the TreeView (TreeModelSort).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function can remove multiple selected rows on a plain TreeView that doesn't implement a fancy TreeModelSort or TreeModelFilter:

```
private void RemoveSelectedRows(TreeView treeView, ListStore listStore)
{
    TreeIter iter;

    TreePath[] treePath = treeView.Selection.GetSelectedRows();

    for (int i  = treePath.Length; i > 0; i--)
    {
        listStore.GetIter(out iter, treePath[(i - 1)]);

        string value = (string)listStore.GetValue(iter, 0);
        Console.WriteLine("Removing: " + value);

        listStore.Remove(ref iter);
    }
}
```

This next function can remove multiple selected rows on a TreeView that DOES implement a TreeModelSort (similar logic can be applied if your TreeView is using a TreeModelFilter):

```
private void RemoveSelectedRows(TreeView treeView, ListStore listStore, TreeModelSort treeModelSort)
{
    TreeModel model;
    TreeIter iter;

    TreePath[] treePath = treeView.Selection.GetSelectedRows(out model);

    for (int i  = treePath.Length; i > 0; i--)
    {
        model.GetIter(out iter, treePath[(i - 1)]);

        string value = (string)model.GetValue(iter, 0);
        Console.WriteLine("Removing: " + value);

        TreeIter childIter = treeModelSort.ConvertIterToChildIter(iter);
        listStore.Remove(ref childIter);
    }
}
```

If anyone has a better way of doing this or sees any bugs in my solution please post a fix, thanks!

Comment: Wow, you answered your own question rather quickly!